# How to handle level shift with ARIMA model?

Tags: r, time-series, arima, structural-change

I have some data that fits an ARIMA(1,1,4) model pretty well and prior to COVID it was a reasonably stable time series. Since COVID, there has been a level shift downward where it continues to be reasonably stable but at volumes around 80% of what they were before. Since we are unsure of when things will return to previous volumes (if ever), I would like to forecast out at this lower level. Is there a best approach for handling this type of data? I have been using Dr. Hyndman's book and the approach I was thinking about was adding a Boolean variable for pre and post COVID using the xreg argument.

I am using R for my analysis if it makes a difference.

Comment: Searching for "arima change point prediction OR forecasting R" returns several relevant results, including R packages that I have not myself used. AFAIK, most of these packages will find a point estimate of the change point and predict using that. If you are interested in just AR(N) models, [the `mcp` package can forecast](https://lindeloev.github.io/mcp/articles/predict.html) taking uncertainty about the change point location into account and with some greater control over priors and model structure. However, it's slow for > 5000 data points. Would you be interested in an AR(N) answer?

Comment: What you are thinking sounds good. Based on your data and reasoning of how Covid has impacted it, you can decide what types of dummy you need to add. For example even though it may be level shift but immediately after the pandemic did it fall a lot more and then came back quickly to 80% or slowly. All this will decide help you decide which types of outliers to be considered. Also read about  `tso` from [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tsoutliers/vignettes/tsoutliers-intro.pdf) `tsoutliers`. It may be of help.